# WordPress page content with html error

Tags: html, wordpress

I found an problem when I was editing the home content in Pages part in WordPress.

Here is the content that I typed in the Pages/home:

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">
   <h3>WHO AM I</h3>
   <p class="content">
       I am a web designer and developer 
   </p>
   <a href="#" class="readmore">View about <span class="arrow">&#8594;</span></a>
</div>
```

The problem is that actually there is no **p** tag wrapping the **a** tag, but when I was checking the page source code from the website, it automatically adds **p** tag around the **a** tag.

```
<p><a class="readmore" href="#">View about <span class="arrow">→</span></a></div>
```

**Tips: In order to avoid the format error, the format of content in the home page is like nodepad format.   NOT USING THE VISUAL EDIT.

Like the following format:**

```
<div class="container"><div class="jumbotron custom-jumbotron center white"><h1>Web Developer</h1><p class="white">Make
```

Does anyone could explain the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be cuz you are using visual editor?

Comment: No closing `</p>` tag after the `</a>`?

Comment: @mc10 yes, that's the most weird point.

Comment: @Mr.Alien no, I am not using the visual editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default behaviour in WordPress. Check the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

However you can disable it entirely by pasting this line into your functions.php file of your theme:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```